# microsoft visual studio ultimate 2013 with update 4 hase stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

When I want to install Visual 2013 in Win8.1 this error apears:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 4 has stopped working
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I Updated My Graphic card My Problem was Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling .net 3.5 by:
Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off